# NodeJS close server and start again

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am brand new to React and NodeJS. I have NodeJS latest version installed on my mac as well as React. I can start and run the app using `npm start` I am following tutorials and it was fine and I could see my app in the browser. The problem begins when I need to finish for the day and start again the next day and I do not know how to start the server again and app and to continue the work. `npm start` does not work. Unfortunately tutorials only show how to start the app for the very first time, but they don't show what do you need to do to interrupt your work, shut down computer and continue the following day. What steps do I need to take in to continue my work the following day?

Comment: Hey Gargamel, if the answer was helpful, can you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding your question the things you want to make sure that whatever project you are working on (nodejs or react) that you cd into the project folder before you run any commands as these scripts you are running "npm run start" etc.. are based on what scripts are written inside the package.json.

so if you use create-react-app for reactjs the "npm run start" is a default script that comes with CRA and will run the app for you.

for express you can also check the scripts and there will be something similar but you can do "node server.js" (or app.js depends on how you called the file you initialize the server) and it will run the server.

in summary:

- make sure to cd into the correct directory
- check package.json for scripts if you are not sure what they are
- also run "npm install" as you might have some missing dependencies
- enjoy.

If you have any more questions will edit my response to answer those as well, have a nice day ;)

Comment: Thank you Michael, Based on your instructions I tried the following: I using cd I am in the right directory where are my app files. I have located the `package.json` file and tried the following instructions `react-scripts start`, `npm start` none of it worked. But strange thing happened. I tried different react app that I have using `npm start` and it did start the app. This is not the first time that for some applications the command `npm start` works and for some it doesn't even though the apps are created the same way. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Michael, I already know what was the problem. I am almost embarrassed to say what it was. It was the location problem. I had an extra folder level there, which I didn't notice. But Thank you for nice summarisation of the steps, which really helped me. Especially when I found that other app worked I noticed it had different folder structure than the one I was using. Now I am in the right folder and using `npm start` works.

Comment: Sure thing, and do not worry it happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for error messages in the Terminal when you run `npm start`. Try to understand them and fix them.

You can also install *Nodemon* (`npm i nodemon`) and run `nodemon {filename}.js` to start the server. `{filename}` is the name of the file in which you're starting the server.

Comment: Thank you I will try this one also. I will post an update here If I run to any issues. Thank you again.